# How to check a users OAuth token using the Slack API's auth.test method

Tags: oauth, slack-api

I'm following the [Sign in with Slack guide](https://api.slack.com/authentication/sign-in-with-slack) to create a user OAuth token and I want to validate the token when a user makes a request to my server, it looks like I should do this using the [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) method, but when I call it with the generated token the request fails with:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "invalid_auth"
}
```

### What I've tried

- Using the generated OAuth token in the API tester (that's on the `auth.test` documentation page) and it fails there too.
- Using a bot OAuth token instead of the Oauth token, that works fine, but I want to validate tokens of users accessing protected routes on my server so the bot token isn't going to work.
- calling the [`openid.connect.userInfo`](https://api.slack.com/methods/openid.connect.userInfo) endpoint with the OAuth token, that works and I can see details of the logged in user but the `auth.test` method has a higher rate limit, and according to the docs `auth.test` should also support user OAuth tokens so that feels like the correct thing to use.

The documentation for the `auth.test` method says no user scopes are required, I request `openid`, `email` and `profile` scopes and the `openid` scope is accepted according to the `openid.connect.userInfo` response.

The user OAuth token I'm passing to the `auth.test` methos is of the format:

```
xoxp-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any idea why the `auth.test` method fails when giving it a token that seems to be a valid user OAuth token (since the `openid.connect.userInfo` endpoint works), and how I can get the method to work?

Comment: Maybe you should contact Slack support. If you're able to successfully call the user info endpoint then it means that the token is valid. It is indeed strange that it gets rejected on the other endpoint. (are both endpoints in the same environment?)